# Python n-ary tree for minimax

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

As a coding project I would like to some kind of an AI for a user to face in my already implemented text-based Connect4 python game. I have researched the most common methods used, and minimax was the primary algorithm used.

If my understanding of the algorithm is correct, I must implement a 7-ary tree, where each node has a board state and 7 children of all possible moves one player can make from that board state.

For implementing this tree, I have decided to use a Node class that has a list of children Nodes and a current state. The tree will only have 3 levels, as keeping a full log of the whole game is unnecessary from my understanding.

The node class is simply:

```
    class _Node(object):
    def __init__(self, state, children=[]):
        self.state = state
        self.children = children
```

And the DecisionTree class a constructor that adds sets the root to None.

However, I would like to understand how the method `add()` would work for an n-ary tree of this kind. The code I wrote up looks like this:

```
    def add(self, state):
    if (self.root == None): 
        self.root = self._Node(state[0]) # state is a singleton list, make that state the root
    else:
        for i in range(len(self.root.children) + 1): # loop over all children of root
            curr = self.root
            while (curr.children != []): # go down in tree until we reach a leaf
                curr = curr.children
            for i in range(len(state)): # add all the new states
                curr.children.append(state[i])
```

My problem here is the while loop, it is obviously not working correctly. It goes from being a Node, as I want, to being a list. I guess I'd have to index children, and therefore take in an index as a parameter. However, indexing an n-ary tree would get messy. How could this be handled? Is using lists a bad idea in general?

Comment: I don't think you can explicitly build the whole tree; it is capped at 42 moves with a branching factor of 7 O(10^35); even 35 moves with an average branching factor of 4 is O(10^21) is beyond feasible ... A more realistic approach is maybe an iterative deepening search, with a good evaluation function.

Comment: Even if the tree only looks at one move at a time? What I mean by this is that this tree will not be a tree of the whole game, just given a single move it makes a tree of that game state, 7 children of all possible moves, then 7 children for each of their children. Meaning this tree will have at most 57 nodes in it. Would the problem be constantly making and deleting this tree?

Comment: You'll have to go deeper than 2 moves to get good results; probably 7-14 moves ahead. Perfect play will require exhaustive search (according to wikipedia and the fhourstone project).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, be carefull with this `def __init__(..., children=[]):`

If you will init your node `children` in that way  then the code like this...

```
a = Node(1)
b = Node(2)
print(a.children, b.children)

a.children.append(3)
print(a.children, b.children)
print(a.children is b.children) # they both point to same object in memory.
```

will produce this output:

```
[] []
[3] [3]
True
```

This is happening because you provide empty list value in constructor and this default value is shared   across all instances.
In other words, after initialization several nodes with this `[]` default children value, children of separate nodes will point to the same list in memory.

Correct way will be to do this like that:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, state, children=None):
        self.state = state
        self.children = children or []
```

Try to fix this  issue first and look if that helps.

Now about the main question. Im my opinion, you can use lists here, but travelling through tree with while loop is not *jedi-path*. We can use recursion here.

In general i can't understand why you need root here, but to travel across tree and add values you can do following:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, state, children=None):
        self.state = state
        self.children = children or []

    def add(self, state):
        if self.children:
            for node in self.children: # loop over all children of root
                node.add(state)            # add all the new states
        else:
            self.state.extend(state)
```

Example:

```
r = Node([3])
r.children = [Node([2]),Node([4]),Node([5])]
print(r.children[0].state)

r.add([25,14])
print(r.children[2].state)

# output will be
[2]
[5, 25, 14]
```

Comment: Thank you, that is very useful to know. I have made the change. May I ask why "children or []"? I am not familiar with this use of Python syntax as my Python in general is still very green.

Comment: @TrueAzure Considering string `children=None` in `__init__` signature, `children or []` means that if you don't provide any non `None` value  while creating  new instance, then new list will be created in that line (because `None or something_else` will always return `something _else`).